# Custom Convert Quote to Order with child object

Tags: apex, trigger, orderitem

Hello I am new to Salesforce.
I want to custom convert Quote to Order with Packaging Details for Order Item.
Packaging_Details__c is the child object of QuoteLineItem and OrderItem objects, An item may have more than one package detail record.
I know the code I wrote is insufficient. Can someone help me?

```java
trigger triggerQuote on Quote (after update) {
        
    switch on Trigger.operationType{
        
        when after_update{
            
            for(Quote singleQ:trigger.new){
                Quote oldQ = Trigger.oldMap.get(singleQ.ID);
                if(oldQ.status != 'Accepted' && singleQ.status == 'Accepted'){
                  triggerQuoteHandler.createOrder(singleQ);  
                }
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public class triggerQuoteHandler {
    
    public static void createOrder(Quote sQuote){
        
        List<QuoteLineItem> listQI = [SELECT Id, QuoteId, Quantity, UnitPrice, TotalPrice, Product2Id 
                                    FROM QuoteLineItem
                                    WHERE QuoteId = :sQuote.id];
        //List<Packaging_Details__c> packs =[SELECT Id, Quote_Line_Item__c FROM Packaging_Details__c WHERE Quote_Line_Item__c IN :listQI];
        Order ord = new Order();

        if(sQuote.Account.RecordTypeId == '0128e000000LDMTAA4'){
           ord.RecordTypeId = '0123H000000An1vQAC'; 
        }else{
           ord.RecordTypeId = '0123H000000An20QAC'; 
        }

        ord.CurrencyIsoCode = sQuote.CurrencyIsoCode;
        ord.AccountId = sQuote.AccountId;
        ord.Status = 'Draft';
        ord.EffectiveDate = Date.Today();
        insert ord;
        
        //List<OrderItem> ordItems = new List<OrderItem>();
        List<Packaging_Details__c> updateToPd = new List<Packaging_Details__c>();
        for(QuoteLineItem singleQI :listQI){
            OrderItem ordItem = new OrderItem();
            ordItem.OrderId = ord.id;
            ordItem.Product2Id = singleQI.Product2Id;
            ordItem.Quantity = singleQI.Quantity;
            ordItem.Vat__c = singleQI.Vat__c;
            ordItem.Unit__c = singleQI.Unit__c;
            insert ordItem;

            for(Packaging_Details__c pd :[SELECT Id, Quote_Line_Item__c FROM Packaging_Details__c WHERE Quote_Line_Item__c = :singleQI.id]){
                pd.Order_Product__c = ordItem.id;
                updateToPd.add(pd);
            }

            //ordItems.add(ordItem);
        }

        //insert ordItems;
        update updateToPd;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your code and found that you have not followed the Salesforce Apex Best Practices.

- Bulkify Your Code
- Avoid DML/SOQL Queries in Loops
- Avoid Hard-coded IDs
- Avoid Nested Loops etc...

I have updated your apex class as below:

```
public class triggerQuoteHandler {
    
    public static void createOrder(Quote sQuote){
        
        List<QuoteLineItem> listQI=[SELECT Id, QuoteId, Quantity, UnitPrice, TotalPrice, Product2Id 
                                    FROM QuoteLineItem
                                    WHERE QuoteId=:sQuote.id];
        List<Packaging_Details__c> packs =[SELECT Id,Quote_Line_Item__c FROM Packaging_Details__c WHERE Quote_Line_Item__c in:listQI ];
        
        Id accountRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('RECORD_TYPE_NAME_HERE').getRecordTypeId();

        Id orderARecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Order.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('RECORD_TYPE_NAME_HERE').getRecordTypeId();
        Id orderBRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Order.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('RECORD_TYPE_NAME_HERE').getRecordTypeId();

        Order ord =  new Order();
        if(sQuote.Account.RecordTypeId==accountRecordTypeId){
           ord.RecordTypeId=orderARecordTypeId; 
        }else{
           ord.RecordTypeId=orderBRecordTypeId; 
        }
        ord.CurrencyIsoCode=sQuote.CurrencyIsoCode;
        ord.AccountId=sQuote.AccountId;
        ord.Status='Draft';
        ord.EffectiveDate=Date.Today();
        insert ord;
        
        Map<Id, OrderItem> mapOfQLIAndOI = new Map<Id, OrderItem>();
        List<OrderItem> ordItems = new List<OrderItem>();        
        for(QuoteLineItem singleQI:listQI){
            OrderItem ordItem = new OrderItem();
            ordItem.OrderId=ord.id;
            ordItem.Product2Id=singleQI.Product2Id;
            ordItem.Quantity=singleQI.Quantity;
            ordItem.Vat__c=singleQI.Vat__c;
            ordItem.Unit__c=singleQI.Unit__c;
            ordItems.add(ordItem);
            mapOfQLIAndOI.put(singleQI.Id, ordItem);
        }

        insert ordItems;


        List<Packaging_Details__c> updateToPd = new List<Packaging_Details__c>();
        for(Packaging_Details__c pd:packs){
                pd.Order_Product__c = mapOfQLIAndOI.get(pd.Quote_Line_Item__c).Id;
                updateToPd.add(pd);
        }
        update updateToPd;        
    }
}
```

In this, Changed the static record type ID to dynamically get the record type ID. Also, added one map to hold the Id of the `QuoteLineItem` and `OrderItem` objects. This map is used to get the Id of the orderItem while updating the packaging details.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to help the OP; suggestion - `mapOfQLIAndOI` - a better naming convention is `orderItemsByQuoteItemId` - that is maps of of Xs keyed by Ys; I find this is immensely helpful at reading code months after I've written it